# How to create an Audio playlist

Tags: views, 6, files, media

Are there **any opportunities to create "classic" playlists** with [Audio](http://drupal.org/project/audio) or any other similar modules? I primarily would like to let mp3-files be played, but in a way that it cannot be easily directly downloaded (considering the fact that [as it's written on Audio module's admin interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL7o1.jpg), *"You should be aware that even when audio is not marked as downloadable, clever users can still download it, this just makes the work harder."*)

After uploading some separate Audio nodes, Audio players can be displayed via Views module like this (with some randomly uploaded tracks):
[image: Audio+Views]

But **this is NOT a good solution for me as it's not like a normal playlist**, as **these are separate audio players**...
There is support in Audio module for the little bit ugly-looking [XSPF Web Music Player - Extended](http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/), but I didn't find any opportunities to create a playlist with it either.

Any suggestions with Audio or any other suitable modules?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The http://drupal.org/project/jplayer module allows for playlists and so forth, but unless you are up for some obfuscated javascript and a whole bunch of other coding (that in the end is nevertheless subvertible [sp?]) the mp3s will still be downloadable by most advanced users.  (Or perhaps investigate the private file serving methods drupal offers, but then you have to balance the overhead there)

Comment: +1, thanks, yes, I know jPlayer, and it's installed too, but I haven't found any ways to let audio files be served so that download links are not in front of the user's face directly. I know advanced users could go round the downloading "obstacle" without a problem, but I just don't want these files to be allowed to be linked to anyone directly. Unfortunately I don't really know how to serve these files from a cache or something similar. I thought I could place these files outside document root and serve them from there. Do you know any kind of methods to do that? Thank you!

Comment: It all depends on how in depth you want to get.  You could edit up the jplayer template and remove the links from the description field so that it justs display the name of the track playing instead of a link to it, but the file names would still be in the source html if your users looked at it.  You might be able to use Drupal's private files method but that requires putting ALL of your site's files there, and I don't know what the overhead would be or is with that method as I've never used it.  Past that, you have to get creative.

Answer (score 0):

Go old school: Revert to flash.

Set it up in any of the multiple free flash media players out there, crate a view block for it, and call it whenever you need it, via panels or what else you may use.

Really, no matter what, people are going to be able to download the music. That is what they do when it streams, after all. If you're worried about DRM/copyright infringements, perhaps you shouldn't be tackling this with commercialized music.

If you just want to have a hotlist of sorts to use for yourself, I wouldn't worry about it too much; if you are creating a portal, or other site, for the streaming of media openly to the internet public, think about lowering the quality considerably, or something else.

Comment: The owner of the site decided he accepts that advanced users can download his music, but he lets users "donate" for it. But as a developer I don't want direct links for these musics to really be easy to find out for noobies. You could be more specific, I know that there are multiple flash players, but I'm looking for a Drupal-solution like using a module, and creating playlists with that. Do you have ideas how to do that in practice?

Answer (score -1):

We have done this [here](http://www.heilsarmee-huttwil.ch/) with [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [AudioField](http://drupal.org/project/audiofield). We are using views to show the list of the individual nodes. Every entry with it's own player. You can even start them in parallel :-).

Originally we were using the audio module. But we had all sorts of problems with this module. Since development has been stopped 2 years ago we went for the CCK & AudioField solution which works great.

Comment: Thanks, but to be honest, I don't really find the answer to my question in your post: you also showed examples with SEPARATE players in their own node, not a real playlist, for example like here: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02/ . I want to achieve something like this. Btw., what kind of problems have you experienced using Audio module (I found this module really useful so far, but maybe I will also experience problems later)? This uses getId3 out of the box, which is really useful for the "investigation" of media files, I don't know what's the case with AudioField that you suggested.

Comment: I did not realize that you need only one player. Sorry. For the audio module: Getting the player to work was a pain and updating drupal or views (if I remember right) often caused it to stop working. Additionally the built in podcast XML support got never accepted by apple which means we were not able to publish podcasts on iTunes.

Comment: OK, no problem, but I also linked a screenshot with the first attempt of listing the tracks (after writing *"After uploading some separate Audio nodes, Audio players can be displayed via Views module like this"*), I thought it's clear this is what I've already achieved using Views. :)
Hmm, strange that you had these problems with this module. I didn't have problems with getting the player to work so far, but the truth is I've never tried it with iTunes podcasts - and I don't have a need for that so far, I just want to play local mp3-files in a playlist. I'd rather place it outside the root...